# If two closed simple curves have the same trace, same starting point and same starting derivative, then they are equal.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

This is not a textbook problem, at least that I'm aware of. I was doodling around with some curves and came to this reasonable conjecture: Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\gamma, \bar\gamma:[a, b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be two regular simple closed curves (so, both are of class $C^{\infty}$ with non vanishing derivative, injective in $[a, b)$, and $\gamma^{(k)}(a)=\gamma^{(k)}(b)$, $\bar\gamma^{(k)}(a)=\bar\gamma^{(k)}(b)$, $\forall k\geq 0$) such that $\gamma([a, b])=A=\bar\gamma([a, b])$, $||\gamma '(t)||=||\bar\gamma '(t)||$ $\forall t\in [a, b]$, $\gamma (a)=\bar\gamma(a)$ and $\gamma ' (a)=\bar\gamma ' (a)$, then $\gamma=\bar\gamma$. I put the last hypothesis so that $\gamma$ and $\bar\gamma$ travel $A$ in the same direction. I still don't know how to attack this problem or even if these hypothesis are enough, so I would appreciate any help with this. Thank you.

Comment: You haven't assumed the curves are regular ($\|\gamma'\|$ everywhere nonzero), but it may not matter because of your injectivity assumption. Have you tried reparametrizing both curves by arclength? You know that the arclengths agree for all $t$ and the traces of the curves are the same curve, so ... if I go distance $s$ along $A$ I must get to the same point either way.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to put there that both are regular curves. I did try using parametrization by arc length, but didn't know where to go from there.

Comment: If you fix a starting point, parametrization by arclength is unique.

Comment: @TedShifrin :0 I didn't know that theorem, in which book can I find it?

Comment: It's considered obvious, so I don't know a place it's proved explicitly. Consider $\beta(s)=\alpha(h(s))$ with $\|\beta'\|=1=\|\alpha'\|$ everywhere. Then $|h'(s)|=1$ for all $s$. Can you finish?

Comment: @TedShifrin I see it now, I feel e little bit embarrassed right now hahaha. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Like Ted Shifrin suggested, the  idea would be that the length of the curve from $\gamma(a)$ to $\gamma(x)$ equals
$$\int_{a}^x \|\gamma'(t)\| dt$$
(this because the function is injective)
so it equals the length from $\gamma(a)= \bar\gamma(a)$ to $\bar\gamma(x)$. Now if they start in the same direction, it follows that $\gamma(x) = \bar\gamma(x)$, for all $x$.

Comment: Looks just as incomplete as my comment :) Maybe save the letter $s$ for arclength, as is customary?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Thank you for  the input , changed the integration variable to $t$. In fact it was a rather complete suggestion, now that I read it carefully :-) !

Comment: @orangeskid I understand the intuiton behind your idea, but still have no clue about where to go from there :/. Can you give me a suggestion?

Comment: @Bruno Aceves: Proving the formula would be useful.   In fact, the length of a curve depends only on the image of it, not on the parametrization.

Comment: @orangeskid How would I prove it? I thought that formula was the definition of arc length.

Comment: @Bruno Aceves: Another approach is to show that in fact $\gamma'(t) =\bar\gamma'(t)$ for all $t$. They have the same length, and they also must have the same direction if not $0$. If $0$, clearly equal. Still, not that clear, since the curve itself may not be regular.

Comment: @orangeskid I will attempt that approach, I added the hypothesis that the curves are regular.